# Check if int from database string is equal to certain value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, integer

I want to check if a Database variable has the value 5 and then change an image.
The Log.d I do before I check with my if statment gives me the value 5 and the headline I want to check for, so the Data is in the Database. But my if-statement is not executed, "Done" is not logged and the image is not changed. Maybe I am using a wrong way to parse the cursor.getString(0) to Integer?
There is no error logged.

```
DbHelper dbh  = new DbHelper(context);
    Cursor cursor = dbh.getScore(dbh);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.d("Database", cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))== 5 && Headline.toString().equals(cursor.getString(1))){
                Log.d("Database","Done");
                ImageDone.setImageResource(R.drawable.markerdone);
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: what is the type of Headline? Are you sure you are comparing it right?

Comment: are you sure Headline.toString().equals(cursor.getString(1)  is true ?

Comment: Headline is a TextView and it's true (as seen in the Log "cursor.getString(1));" there is a row where Headline is true and cursor.getString(0) is 5...)

Comment: To be sure that Headline is not the problem, try to remove the equals condition and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know why I didn't try this earlier. I set Headline also in onCreate and it seems that wasn't already set when I checked if it equals. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i was trying to parse int from Mysql DB so i fixed it like this :

```
 if (Math.round(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(0))== 5 && Headline.toString().equals(cursor.getString(1))){
            Log.d("Database","Done");
            ImageDone.setImageResource(R.drawable.markerdone);
        }
```